# ¿Como puedo hacer que un String con características validadas por el programa sea guardado en un vector por posiciones?

Tags: java, string, poo, charts, static

**Necesito que el programa valide que el String que ingrese el usuario tenga seis caracteres, eso lo logré. pero no soy capaz de de que esos caracteres sean guardados en un vector en el orden de inicio. Por ejemplo si la palabra es Hola vector[0]=H, vector[1]=o, vector[2]=l, vector[3]=a y cuando la palabra se acabe el sepa que se acabo y deje de recorrerla. Esto es para analizar en cada posición que hay y si cumple con x característica que sucede algo.
esto es lo que he intentado:**

```
public class Strings {
static int contador=0;
static String palabra;
static final char vec[]= new char [palabra.length()];
public Strings() {
}

public Strings(String palabra){
    Strings.palabra =  palabra;
}
public String getPalabra() {
    return palabra;
}

public void setPalabra(String palabra) {
     Strings.palabra = palabra;
}
public int validar(){
     Strings obj = new Strings();
     String sMiCadena = obj.getPalabra();
    int n = sMiCadena.length();
    if(n==6){
        contador=sMiCadena.length();
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
    }

public void caracterizar(){
     Strings obj = new Strings();
      String cadena = obj.getPalabra();
      contador=cadena.length();
     if(obj.validar()==1){
         for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length() ; i++) {
             vec[i]=cadena.charAt(i);
         }
     }
}

    public void mostarCaracterizar(){
     Strings obj = new Strings();
      String cadena = obj.getPalabra();
      contador=cadena.length();
     if(obj.validar()==1){
         for (int i = 0; i < palabra.length() ; i++) {
             System.out.println("el vec es. "+vec[i]);
         }
     }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Strings obj = new Strings();
    obj.setPalabra(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "digite palabra"));
    if(obj.validar()==1){
    System.out.println(""+obj.getPalabra());
    obj.mostarCaracterizar();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("el numero que ingresó no cumple con las caracteristicas solicitadas");
    }
}
```

Comment: Saludos. No pones alguna referencia de aproximadamente donde se genera el error; lo que puedo observar es que `caracterizar`no es llamada en ningun momento de tu código; que es donde al parecer llevar variable `vec`. Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: No, es que realmente no sé donde está el error ¿Conoces una forma funcional de dividir una palabra en sus caracteres y después guardarla en un vector en orden de posición? @RobertoLeOr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que lo que quieres es convertir el string a un arreglo de char, puedes utilizar esto:

```
vec = cadena.toCharArray();
```

También puede que te salga ese error porque  inicialmente el String palabra no tiene tamaño. lo unico que hice fue no inicializar el String palabra  y el char vector, luego les dije que eran en el metodo caracterizar, y despues recuerda que cuando quieras llamar a una variable que este en otro metodo debes llamar al metodo, que fue lo que hice en Mostrar Caracterizar.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class string {
static int contador=0;
static String palabra ;
static  char vec[];
public string() {
}

public string(String palabra){
    string.palabra =  palabra;
}
public String getPalabra() {
    return palabra;
}

public void setPalabra(String palabra) {
     string.palabra = palabra;
}
public int validar(){
     string obj = new string();
     String sMiCadena = obj.getPalabra();
    int n = sMiCadena.length();
    if(n==6){
        contador=sMiCadena.length();
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
    }

public void caracterizar(){
     string obj = new string();
      String cadena = obj.getPalabra();
      contador=cadena.length();
     if(obj.validar()==1){
       this.vec = cadena.toCharArray();
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vec));
     }
}

    public void mostarCaracterizar(){
        caracterizar();
     string obj = new string();
      String cadena = obj.getPalabra();
      contador=cadena.length();
     if(obj.validar()==1){
         
             System.out.println("el vec es. " +  Arrays.toString(vec));
         
     }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    string obj = new string();
    obj.setPalabra(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "digite palabra"));
    if(obj.validar()==1){
    System.out.println(""+obj.getPalabra());
    obj.mostarCaracterizar();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("el numero que ingresó no cumple con las caracteristicas solicitadas");
    }
}
```

}